# How do I tell my dockerised Spring Boot Neo4J application to talk to my Neo4j server?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-data-neo4j

I have an "out of the box" Spring Data Neo4j application that works fine when talking to a Neo4j server running on my box.    By "out of the box" I mean that  the only config I have done in the app is specify the username and password for Neo4j.

The app (run with ./gradlew bootRun) works fine with a dockerised Neo4j server as well.

When I build a docker image of this app, it fails to connect to the Neo4j server, whether or not that is dockerised.

When it works, it says:

> 2019-01-18 12:58:49.311  INFO 18345 --- [  restartedMain] Driver                                   : Direct driver instance 1080149308 created for server address localhost:7687

When it doesn't work, it says:

> 2019-01-18 02:27:53.760  INFO 1 --- [           main] Driver                                   : Direct driver instance 707892422 created for server address localhost:7687
>
> 2019-01-18 02:27:54.100  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConnectionPool                           : Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687
>
> [...]
>
> Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:7687

I've tried linking the two dockers (app and Neo4j docker) with --link.   Same result.

I've tried composing them:

```
version: '3'

services:
  docker-neo:
    image: neo4j:3.5
    ports:
      - 7687:7687
      - 7474:7474

  godojo:
    image: com.greenasjade.j01/j01
    depends_on:
      - docker-neo
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

No joy.

I need to end up with a dockerised solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer which refers to MySQL but explains the networking issue.

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Bottom line though, if you're on linux add --network="host" and if you're on windows or mac change the neo4j host in your Spring Boot configuration to be  host.docker.internal. To do taht edit your application.properties or application.yml file.

`spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://host.docker.internal:7687`

Documentation for Spring Boot's Neo4j support is here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-neo4j

Comment: How do I "change the neo4j host in your Spring Boot configuration to be host.docker.internal."?  Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an explanation of how to configure the neo4j connection.

Comment: Thanks, the link is a great help. I might be inching forwards.   First it failed because you have to specify the protocol in the uri (`bolt://host.docker.internal:7687`).  Once over that, now it fails during building the Docker image because the test fails with "cant connect to host".     I'm guessing that's because the test is running as a local machine test, not a docker image?   Can you help witih that?

Comment: Hah -x test for the build, and now I am in business!   Thanks!

Comment: I've since discovered that host.docker.internal is an OS specific feature, which is obviously not ideal.   Is there a more ideal solution, that ports from development on OSX (where it works) to some varieties of linux  - eg Amazon EC2 - (where it doesn't)?